# What permissions are required to perform Azure DevOps API calls for leases of builds

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I am trying to figure out a way I can remove leases on specific builds via the AzureDevOps API. I have a PAT with read/execute permissions on Builds and read/write permissions on test management. I've also tried various other permissions without anything working. Below is the script I am trying to use.

```
$token = "{PAT}"
$url="https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/retention/leases/{lease Id}?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
```

When I try to get or delete builds this works fine (with a different URL of course). But when I try to get a lease I always get a 401 error. I've looked all over the API documentation but I can't find anywhere it says specifically what permissions the PAT needs to gain access. What specific permissions are required for the leases? Or do I just need to go about formatting my header in a different way?

Thanks for any help, please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this doc [Leases - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1):

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids={ids}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

PAT scope is: `vso.build_execute`

By the way, I try to switch the doc version to Azure DevOps Server 2019, but I get the message: `The requested page is not available for Azure DevOps Server 2019`

You could try to catch the API via F12 and then check it in the NetWork tab.

**Update1**

Thanks for Andrew sharing.

We could vote or follow this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-get-or-delete-leases-with-api-calls-in-the-az/1398169?from=email) to get the latest news.

**Update2**

If we create PAT token with full access, we could get and delete leases, check the pic below

GET

[image]

DELETE

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am on Azure DevOps Server 2020, sorry I should have mentioned that. And I tried using f12 but it seems the lease information comes with the initial call, but its possible I'm not reading the calls correctly. I know for fact my PAT has vso.build_execute permissions because I'm able to get and delete builds. I tried the URL you posted but it still doesn't work with my PAT. Is there any reason I wouldn't be able to get the leases but still get the builds?

Comment: I realize that because server 2020 doesn't have any docs it probably means I'm limited to the implementation of server 2019. Does this just mean I can't get/delete leases with API calls?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, It seems that we cannot get or delete leases with API calls in the Azure DevOps Server, I also try it with Azure DevOps Service and get 500 issue, I recommend that you report this issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?from=email&viewtype=all&space=21&entry=problem), the product team will check it and  investigate this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks for testing that. I made a post available here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-get-or-delete-leases-with-api-calls-in-the-az/1398169?from=email

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I have updated the answer and added the ticket link, you could check it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, If we create PAT with full access scope, and then we could get and delete leases with the Token and REST API. You could check the update2

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This API needs leaseId but I have a build, how to get it's leases in Azure DevOps Server 2020?